# How to show COUNT for each day of the month

Tags: postgresql

Using Postgresql

```
SELECT 

    COUNT(visit.visit_disch_date)
    FROM
    visit
WHERE
 visit.visit_disch_date >= '2022-12-01' AND visit.visit_disch_date < '2022-12-31' AND 
    visit.visit_stay_type = '1'
```

I'm trying to get the individual count for each day in December. Output would look like:

12-01-2022   4
12-02-2022   5
12-03-2022   7

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: Why is December 3rd with a count of **7** when 2nd of December has a count of **5**?

Comment: I can only get it to spit out the entire total for the month. I would like to have the output look like it does row by row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  DATE(visit.visit_disch_date) as Date_of_Discharge,
    COUNT(visit.visit_disch_date) AS Number_of_Discharges
    FROM
    visit
    WHERE
    visit.visit_disch_date BETWEEN '2022-12-01' AND '2022-12-31' AND
    visit.visit_stay_type = '1'
    GROUP BY
    DATE(visit.visit_disch_date)
```